# How to make the same Gimp bright curve?

Tags: curve, bezier

Now I'm trying to implement with MS Excel to make the same Gimp bright curve.
So I used Bezier equation for making the curve like the following.
[image]
You can see the curve of the Bezier.

But there are some problems.
As you can see, the point B and C were not drawn exactly my expectation.
I think the following red curve which is exactly showing my expectation.
[image]
But I don't know what am I supposed to do that to make right curve.
Please advice me.

Note, the equation like this.

=$D$2*(1-F2)^3+3*$D$3*F2*(1-F2)^2+3*$D$4*(F2)^2*(1-F2)+(F2^3*$D$5)

=$E$2*(1-F2)^3+3*$E$3*F2*(1-F2)^2+3*$E$4*(F2)^2*(1-F2)+(F2^3*$E$5)

Update :
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly do you mean by "GIMP bright curve" (or at least provide a screenshot where you've found it)? Plus, I heavily suspect that red curve that you've drawn by hand is *not* "exactly showing" your expectations (at the very least due to curve having multiple Y values for X ~ 1 and going for X > 1).

Comment: I don't see any updates. What exactly have you updated and how? There's no sign of original post being edited.

Comment: You do realize that a Bezier spline does not necessarily *interpolate* (i.e. pass through) all its control points, right? If you want something that passes through all of the points you specify, then Bezier (and in fact, most other types of splines as well) is not what you want... You should look into polynomial curves in that case...

Comment: @GreyCat I have update the GIMP bright curve. Please check this out

Comment: @twalberg Thanks Sir, Yes, I realized that a Bezier Curve does not necessarily to interpolate all control points. Did you mean that the above curve not using the Bezier ?

Comment: @twalberg Sir, Would you please let me know some reference to guide? I don't know where to start from..